# YARD is not the same as RDoc?

Tags: ruby, rdoc, yard

Correct me if I'm wrong, is [YARD](http://yardoc.org/) not the same as [RDoc](https://ruby.github.io/rdoc/)?

It's not based on RDoc but a total rewrite?

So if I'm using YARD, I don't have to bother with RDoc right?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In short: Yes. (To all three questions.)

Note that YARD is mostly backwards-compatible with RDoc, at least as far as the markup is concerned. (RDoc plugins OTOH don't work with YARD.) So, you can actually use YARD to process your legacy RDoc files. YARD is mostly a proper superset of RDoc.

Comment: So you feel that Yard is the way to go?

Comment: @ajsie: I haven't used RDoc in over a year, and never looked back.